# ESP32 Neopixel acting strange when using dual core functionality

Tags: arduino, esp32, ws2812b, multicore

I have just started using ESP32 and tested dual core functionality, which works fine i.e. can blink two leds with different blink intervals parallelly. Also I've tested touch sensors, they also works fine. Problem came when I combined both. Actually I wanted to execute touch detection in one core and control neopixel led strip(WS2812) in another core.

Below is the code I am using:-

```
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>

TaskHandle_t ConnectTask;

#define LED_PIN 26
#define LED_COUNT 300
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip(LED_COUNT, LED_PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

int touch[] = {27, 14, 12, 13};
boolean touchStarted[] = {false, false, false, false};
unsigned long touchTime[] = {0, 0, 0, 0};

int threshold = 90;
int touchMinDuration = 100;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  strip.begin();
  strip.show();
  strip.setBrightness(50);

  xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(Connect, "Connect", 10000, NULL, 1, &ConnectTask, 0);
  delay(500);
}

void loop() {
  colorWipe(strip.Color(255,   0,   0), 50);
  colorWipe(strip.Color(  0, 255,   0), 50);
  colorWipe(strip.Color(  0,   0, 255), 50);

  theaterChase(strip.Color(127, 127, 127), 50);
  theaterChase(strip.Color(127,   0,   0), 50);
  theaterChase(strip.Color(  0,   0, 127), 50);

  rainbow(10);
  theaterChaseRainbow(50);
}

void Connect( void * pvParameters ) {
  for (;;) {
    checkTouch(); // works fine if comment this
    delay(10);
  }
}

void checkTouch(){
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    int t = touchRead(touch[i]);
    if (t < threshold && !touchStarted[i]) { // touched
      touchStarted[i] = true;
      touchTime[i] = millis();
    } else if (t >= threshold && touchStarted[i]) { // touched not
      if (millis() - touchTime[i] > touchMinDuration)
        touched(i);
      touchStarted[i] = false;
    }
  }
}

void touched(int id)
{
  switch (id) {
    case 0: Serial.println("TOUCH 1"); break;
    case 1: Serial.println("TOUCH 2"); break;
    case 2: Serial.println("TOUCH 3"); break;
    case 3: Serial.println("TOUCH 4"); break;
  }
}

void colorWipe(uint32_t color, int wait) {
  for (int i = 0; i < strip.numPixels(); i++) {
    strip.setPixelColor(i, color);
    strip.show();
    delay(wait);
  }
}

void theaterChase(uint32_t color, int wait) {
  for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
    for (int b = 0; b < 3; b++) {
      strip.clear();
      for (int c = b; c < strip.numPixels(); c += 3) {
        strip.setPixelColor(c, color);
      }
      strip.show();
      delay(wait);
    }
  }
}

void rainbow(int wait) {
  for (long firstPixelHue = 0; firstPixelHue < 5 * 65536; firstPixelHue += 256) {
    for (int i = 0; i < strip.numPixels(); i++) {
      int pixelHue = firstPixelHue + (i * 65536L / strip.numPixels());
      strip.setPixelColor(i, strip.gamma32(strip.ColorHSV(pixelHue)));
    }
    strip.show();
    delay(wait);
  }
}

void theaterChaseRainbow(int wait) {
  int firstPixelHue = 0;
  for (int a = 0; a < 30; a++) {
    for (int b = 0; b < 3; b++) {
      strip.clear();

      for (int c = b; c < strip.numPixels(); c += 3) {
        int      hue   = firstPixelHue + c * 65536L / strip.numPixels();
        uint32_t color = strip.gamma32(strip.ColorHSV(hue));
        strip.setPixelColor(c, color);
      }
      strip.show();
      delay(wait);
      firstPixelHue += 65536 / 90;
    }
  }
}
```

Problem with this code is that led strip working strangely i.e. strip turn white and starts performing white spiral loop at certain intervals (Let me know if video is needed).

If I comment this line:-

> checkTouch();

inside **Connect** task. Strip animation works as expected. I can't understand why **Connect** task is interfering with **loop()** when they are running on separate cores, also **Connect** task don't have any code for neopixel control, just checking touches (touch functionality is working i.e. prints "TOUCH 1" etc).

Comment: are you using wifi? that takes up a core.

Comment: It's entirely possible that you're running into conflicts when accessing the hardware I/O from both cores (if you are even achieving that).  Both your touch detection and your LED strip pattern may be written in ways which assume exclusively mastery of the hardware and end up misoperating a bit if they have to wait their turn to do something.  With so much of the functionality hidden from the question by being buried deep in library code, it's hard to speculate what the exact issue is.

Comment: So what might help in debugging, any clue? That's the exact code I am using and just one library <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>.